# neo4j-import: NodeLabelUpdates must be supplied in order of ascending node id

Tags: csv, neo4j

While trying to import a csv produced from wikipedia data I get the following error:

```
rolf@shogun:~$ neo4j-import --into wiki.db --id-type string --bad-tolerance 12998873 --skip-bad-relationships true --multiline-fields true --nodes:Page entities2.csv --relationships:LINK links2.csv --stacktrace true --skip-duplicate-nodes true
Importing the contents of these files into wiki.db:
Nodes:
  :Page
  /home/rolf/entities2.csv
Relationships:
  :LINK
  /home/rolf/links2.csv

Available memory:
  Free machine memory: 25.75 GB
  Max heap memory : 6.98 GB

Nodes
[>:??-------------|*PROPERTIES----------|NODE:7.63 MB---|LABEL SCAN-----------|v:??------------]100k
Done in 485ms
Prepare node index
[*RESOLVE (2412 collisions):15.61 MB-----------------------------------------------------------] 90k
Done in 377ms
Calculate dense nodes
[>:27.21 MB/|PREPARE---------------|*DIVIDE----------------------------------------------------]  4M
Done in 52s 534ms
Relationships
[*>:136.04 MB/s---------------------|PREPARE(2)========================|PROPERT|v:208.52 MB/s--]  7M
Done in 10s 453ms
Node --> Relationship
Import error: NodeLabelUpdates must be supplied in order of ascending node id
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NodeLabelUpdates must be supplied in order of ascending node id
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.write(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.UpdateNodeRecordsStep.update(UpdateNodeRecordsStep.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.UpdateNodeRecordsStep.update(UpdateNodeRecordsStep.java:38)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.UpdateRecordsStep.process(UpdateRecordsStep.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.UpdateRecordsStep.process(UpdateRecordsStep.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProcessorStep$4.run(ProcessorStep.java:120)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProcessorStep$4.run(ProcessorStep.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:237)
```

I've tried filtering out & and / but still the same error (was mentioned in a similar question).

The relationships csv (links2.csv) contains mostly references that don't exist in entities2.csv since it's only a small segment of the data.

I'm using neo4j 2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that is already fixed in the codebase, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/45520e329403e166743b0027e75f2f658019ceae. You could either wait for 2.2.6 or next release in 2.3 branch (either another milestone or RC). Alternatively grab the sources and build a snapshot on your own.